# What is necessary to make this JS conditional formula work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, formula

I have this JS formula for detecting out of range batch numbers, my boss reports it always returns No to them, but in my case it always returns Yes. The formula is the following:

```
drug_administrated = 'Azacitidine' 
kit_1_d1 = 1100

if

({drug_administrated} = 'Azacitidine' && ( {kit_1_d1} < 1000 || {kit_1_d1} >1116)) {

"No";

}else if

({drug_administrated} = 'Vidaza' && ({kit_1_d1} < 3000 || {kit_1_d1} > 3096) ) {

"No";

}else {

"Yes";

}
```

In this case it should return Yes and it does
But if I place for instance

```
drug_administrated = 'Azacitidine' 
kit_1_d1 = 100

if

({drug_administrated} = 'Azacitidine' && ( {kit_1_d1} < 1000 || {kit_1_d1} >1116)) {

"No";

}else if

({drug_administrated} = 'Vidaza' && ({kit_1_d1} < 3000 || {kit_1_d1} > 3096) ) {

"No";

}else {

"Yes";

}
```

It should return No, but stills returns Yes.

I should admit that I'm a total noob self taught js apprentice, and I'd truly appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple syntax issues in the code sample you have supplied:

1) Use the proper [equality comparisons operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison), majority of the time you should be using `===` to compare the value and type of objects being compared. You are using an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment) which initializes a value.

2) Do not wrap the variables in `{}`

3) You are not actually returning a value anywhere.

```js
function check(drug, kit) {
  // use correct comparison operator === and dont wrap the var in {}
  if (drug === 'Azacitidine' && (kit < 1000 || kit > 1116)) {
    // return a value to process
    return "No";
  } else if (drug === 'Vidaza' && (kit < 3000 || kit > 3096)) {
    return "No";
  } else {
    return "Yes";
  }
}

console.log(check('Azacitidine', 100));
console.log(check('Azacitidine', 1000));

console.log(check('Vidaza', 1000));
console.log(check('Vidaza', 3000));
```

Highly recommend you review the document on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to help learn the language.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I have fixed the bug. Kudos to the contributors :)